# Why does my toothbrush topple on rebound?

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, everyday-life

I noticed this with my toothbrush the other day, but I feel that I have witnessed it happening before.

I accidentally knocked my hand into my toothbrush (electric toothbrush, can stand upright on its own). It surged up and started tilting as if it was about to fall over, but it didn't. On rebound, however, it did fall over, in the direction towards my hand where I initially struck it.

How can this happen? If the CG did not move laterally enough to cause a tip-over before, then how did it gain enough kinetic energy to topple on rebound? Has anyone else witnessed something like this happening before?

Edit: On u/march's suggestion, I took some videos and was able to replicate the phenomenon. Here are the relevant stills:

At strike:

[image]

At peak rightward motion:

[image]

Toppling over leftward:

[image]

Comment: One possibility is that on the rebound, the toothbrush slips along the counter in the opposite direction as the rebound, enough to move the center of mass past the pivot point.  Can you repeat the "experiment" and closely watch the base of the toothbrush to see if there is any slipping?  There would still be a question as to *why* it slips in one direction and not the other, but that could be a matter of just analyzing at what point during the motion does the counter have to exert the largest frictional force, and maybe that only happens on the rebound.

Comment: Does it happen the other way as well?

Comment: I tried a few tests were I released it from rest at peak tilt both left and right and couldn't get it to topple. I also tried striking it from the right and wasn't able to reproduce, but I only have so much patience...

Is there a way to embed a video in the post? There is a small wobbling motion that may explain it. It seems like it is not purely left-right motion.

Comment: I think you have to upload it to an external site and then post the link here. I am interested to see it and it might be of some help.

Comment: It can have a little spinning at beginning.

Comment: Maybe the weight of the toothbrush is off-center. Do the batteries go in in one side of the base instead of the other?

Comment: How level is the counter where the brush sits?  If you tap the brush from the right, does it fall to the right or to the left?